# problem while passing function as parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
function initialize(final) {
        /* ........ */
        var address_array = final.split('~');


        for (var count = 0; count < address_array.length; count++) 
        {
            if (geocoder) {
                geocoder.getLatLng(
                    address_array[count],
                    function (point) {
                        if (!point) {
                            alert(address_array[count] + " not found");
                        }
```

All I want is the alert to work over here, in the last line.

Suppose `address_array` has 3 values, i.e `address_array.length` is 3. But the alert is always showing `undefined not found`. I am assuming `address_array[count]` cannot be accessed from this function. However when I try

```
alert(address_array.length + " not found");
```

it says `3 not found`. please help.

can anyone please help me regarding this issue?

function makeTheFunction(array, thisCount) {
          return function (point) {
              if (!point) {
                  alert(array[thisCount] + " not found");
              }

```
          else {
              var marker = new GMarker(point);
              map.addOverlay(marker);
              GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                  marker.openInfoWindowHtml(array[thisCount] + "</b>");
              });
          }
      };
  }
```

the alert(array[thisCount] + " not found"); is working fine but it doenst seem to work when it goes into the else section ..marker.openInfoWindowHtml(array[thisCount] + "");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because your function is a closure over the `count` variable, and closures get an *enduring reference* to the variable, not a *copy* of its value as of when the function is defined. So all copies of the function see `count` as of the end of the loop, which is outside the range of the array -- hence the `undefined`.

What you want to do is create the function such that it closes over something that doesn't change.

```
var address_array = final.split('~');

for (var count = 0; count < address_array.length; count++) 
{
    if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.getLatLng(
            address_array[count],
            makeTheFunction(address_array, count)
        );
    }
}

function makeTheFunction(array, thisCount)
{
    return function(point) {
        if (!point) {
            alert(array[thisCount] + " not found");
        }
    };
}
```

We pass both the array reference and the `count` *value* as of each iteration of the loop into `makeTheFunction`, which creates the function as a closure over its arguments and returns that function. Now the function will show the right information, because the information it's closing over doesn't change. Note that as written, `makeTheFunction` can be outside of any other function so as to avoid having the closure close over anything else.

More about closures: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Comment: ya, even when i write 
alert(count + " not found"); it shows 3 not found.
how to tackle with the problm??

Comment: @Anargha: I've included an example approach. My guess is I added it *just after* you saw the answer. :-)

Comment: ya. i saw ur answer but i m not able to grasp what exactly is going wrong.there is a 2nd part,the else part. there also i m not able to access the array[thiscount].. !!! 

 else {
                        
                        var marker = new GMarker(point);
                        map.addOverlay(marker);
                        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                            marker.openInfoWindowHtml(value + "</b>");
                        });
                  }

Comment: @Anargha: Regarding the second part, you just do the same thing I've done above: Create a function that creates the actual function you'll give to `addEventListener`. I think things will be clearer if you read through the article linked above.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function initialize(final) {
        /* ........ */
        var address_array = final.split('~');

        for (var count = 0; count < address_array.length; count++) 
        {
            doGeocode(address_array[count]);
        }
}

function doGeocode(value){
    if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.getLatLng(
        value,
        function (point) {
            if (!point) {
                alert(value + " not found");
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: there is a 2nd part,the else part. there also i m not able to access the value. !!! 
else { var marker = new GMarker(point); map.addOverlay(marker); GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function () { marker.openInfoWindowHtml(value + "</b>"); }); }